# Is there a way to turn off syntax highlighting in testing-library

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, testing-library, vue-testing-library

I am using @testing-library/vue and run the tests within a build step of Sublime Text. The error output uses prettyDom and isn't very legible in the output window:

Example Output in Build Results window:

```
     TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find a label with the text of: /val1/

[36m<div[39m
  [33mclass[39m=[32m"Cell"[39m
  [33mdata-v-1cdb88a0[39m=[32m""[39m
  [33mstyle[39m=[32m"width: 40%;"[39m
[36m>[39m
  [36m<div[39m
    [33mclass[39m=[32m"Label"[39m
    [33mdata-v-1cdb88a0[39m=[32m""[39m
  [36m>[39m
    [0mTest Cat #1[0m
  [36m</div>[39m
  [36m<div[39m
    [33mattrs[39m=[32m"[object Object]"[39m
    [33mdata-v-088d7313[39m=[32m""[39m
    [33mdata-v-1cdb88a0[39m=[32m""[39m
    [33mform[39m=[32m"[object Object]"[39m
    [33mon[39m=[32m"[object Object]"[39m
    [33mprops[39m=[32m"[object Object]"[39m
```

Is there a way to turn off the syntax highlighting with an environment variable like you can to extend the output length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apparent answer is to get Sublime Text to display the colors in the build window by using the ANSIescape plugin:

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/ansi-color-codes-in-build-output/11296/16
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ANSIescape

Answer (score 1):

Syntax highlighting is handled by the editor displaying the text.

In Sublime Text you can effectively remove – *turn off* if you like – the syntax highlighting of the current file / buffer by changing the syntax to `Plain Text`.

You can do that by choosing `Plain Text` after clicking on the active syntax name on the right of the `Status Bar` or from the `View --> Syntax` menu, or by opening the `Command Palette` and selecting the `Set Syntax: Plain Text` command.

Comment: This question is not about syntax highlighting within Sublime Text editors. It is about the attempted highlighting done by @testing-library/vue that cannot be displayed correctly in the build results window within Sublime Text.

Answer (score 1):

prettyDOM takes the same options as [pretty-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty-format). One of those options is "highlight". In pretty-format it seems to be false by default, but in prettyDOM I found it's true by default. You can disable it like this:

```
prettyDOM(myDom, undefined, {highlight: false})
```

Comment: The problem is that @testing-library/vue is making the call to prettyDOM in its automatic logging and I don't see a way to globally set whether it uses highlight or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `COLORS` environment variable to `false` to turn off colourisation. See https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-debugging/

Although your question relates to the build results window in Sublime, this is a common problem in other places where the colour codes make it hard to see the actual debug output (in my case a Jenkins console output when tests fail).